# реализация стека контейнера

Tags: stl, стек

Возник такой вопрос
есть контейнер вектор,нужно переделать под стек
не понимаю,что делать с итератором,ведь в стеке его нет

```
void Container::add(Base * p)
{
    vec.push_back(p);
}

Container::~Container()
{
    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++)
        delete (*i);
}

void Container::ToString(std::stringstream & ss) const
{
    ss << '[';

    for (auto i = vec.begin(); i != vec.end(); i++)
    {
        if (i != vec.begin())
            ss << ',';
        (*i)->ToString(ss);
    }

    ss << ']';
}
```

Comment: Собственно, а для чего делать такую обертку для контейнера ? Почему бы не унаследовать класс от вектора или того же стека, если уж вы хотели добавить свой функционал ?

Comment: это все необходимо для дальнейшего решения задачи
по сути, мне лишь нужно сделать тоже самое для стека
вся моя проблема в итераторе
который ,по сути, нужен для вывода схемы контейнера на экран

Comment: Просто создавайте копию и вытаскивайте по элементу, вот и будет вам вывод.